# How to install pandoc-crossref

Tags: haskell, r-markdown, cabal, pandoc

I would like cross-reference figures in rMarkdown, and pandoc-crossref seems to be a common solution (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37116632/rmarkdown-html-number-figures)). The instructions on pandoc's Github page say:

> Assuming you already installed Haskell platform, you can install pandoc-crossref with cabal:
>   `cabal update`
>   `cabal install pandoc-crossref`

So I installed Haskell from [here](https://www.haskell.org/platform/). However, when I try to run `cabal update` in the GHCi terminal, I just get an error: 
[image]

So, how do I install pandoc-crossref?

Comment: All cabal commands should be run from the command line, not from GHCi.

Comment: Please don't paste images of problems, just the text will do.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson how was I to know that the error message itself was not relevant here?

Comment: The `pandoc-citeproc` binary is shipped with pandoc. Best to save yourself some trouble and just download it from the [download page](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases/).

Comment: @filups21 I was suggesting you use text instead of images, not omit the information entirely.  Pictures of code and errors are usually less helpful than copy/paste-able blocks of text.

Answer (score 2):

`cabal` is a binary from the `cabal-install` package and not a Haskell function.  You should execute programs from a command line and not within GHCi.  It looks like you are using windows so there might be some steps to find the program but once you do you should be able to call it directly.