# Auto-Numbering of Figure and Table Captions for HTML Output in R Markdown

Tags: r-markdown, knitr, bookdown

Is there a way to automatically number the figures in captions when I knit R Markdown document into an HTML format?

What I would like is for my output to be the following:

> Figure 1: Here is my caption for this amazing graph.

However, I am currently getting the following:

> Here is my caption for this amazing graph.

Here is my MWE:

````
---
title: "My title"
author: "Me"
output: 
  html_document:
  number_sections: TRUE
  fig_caption: TRUE
---

```{r setup}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo=FALSE)
```

```{r plot1,fig.cap="Here is my caption for this amazing graph."}
x <- 1:10
y <- rnorm(10)
plot(x,y)
```

```{r table1, fig.cap="Here is my caption for an amazing table."}
head(mtcars, 2)
```
````

I have read that this issue is resolved with Bookdown but I've read the Definitive Guide to Bookdown, cover to cover, and can't find it.

Comment: After answering this question, I realised in was a possible duplicate of [R Markdown HTML Number Figures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37116632/r-markdown-html-number-figures). However, the answer lacked any decent answers which used **bookdown** so I have added a similar answer to this other post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you wish to have numbered figures, you will need to use an output format provided by bookdown. These include `html_document2`, `pdf_document2` etc. See [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/bookdown-output.html) for a more comprehensive list of options.

Changing your document example `html_document` to `bookdown::html_document2` will resolve your problem.

````
---
title: "My title"
author: "Me"
output: 
  bookdown::html_document2:
  number_sections: TRUE
  fig_caption: TRUE
---

```{r setup}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo=FALSE)
```

```{r plot1,fig.cap="Here is my caption for this amazing graph."}
x <- 1:10
y <- rnorm(10)
plot(x,y)
```

```{r plot2, fig.cap="Here is my caption for another amazing graph."}
plot(y,x)
```
````

If you want to label tables created by `knitr::kable`, you will need to specify the caption within the table call itself

````
```{r table1}
knitr::kable(mtcars[1:5, 1:5], caption = "Here is an amazing table")
```
````

Comment: Awesome thanks Mikey. I realized that fig.cap doesn't work with tables. Is there a tbl.cap?

Comment: Also helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64896314/how-to-generate-automatic-numbering-of-table-titles-in-word-using-knit-in-rmarkd