# Automatically number figures in rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I run this code but it does not number my  figure

````
## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example (Figure \@ref(fig:titanic))

```{r titanic, fig.cap='(ref:titanic)'}
plot(pressure)
```
````

What is missing? Do I need to load a library that I am unaware of? The plot looks like this: 
[image]

My file starts like this:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output:
  html_document:
    fig_caption: true
---
```

Comment: @ Mikko: No but I have now, see editet question. Still the same.

Comment: @ Mikko: I have updated the YAML header again with the style you wrote but still no change.. Does it look right?

Comment: Nice that it worked. No shame in making duplicates sometimes :) I will delete the comments once the question is marked as a duplicate by the community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37116632/r-markdown-html-number-figures). The answers list several ways to address the problem, and setting your document to `bookdown::html_document2` appears to be the simplest solution. I.e. modify your YAML header:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: bookdown::html_document2
---
```