# Create word document with dynamic number of images with RMarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have saved the 2 images below into my working directory named `bl_convergence_acorr001.png` and `bl_convergence_acorr002.png` respectively. My goal is to add those images in a word document. But the number of images may not be static like this example but dynamic. So my thought was to create a list in which those names will be saved. The same logic must be applied for the titles as well. The first should be named `Figure 1`, the second `Figure 2` etc. How can I pass the code that adds the image inside the `for()` loop?

1st.
[image]
2nd.
[image]

````
 ---
title: "My Title"
author: "Me"
date:  "1/1/2016"
output: bookdown::word_document2
---


```{r cars, echo=FALSE,fig.cap = ". (m_BARI_POP1_3_PRIMARY_12_ACR20_independent_fixed_fixed, logit_independent_fixed_fixed) Baseline Autocorrelation plots"}
knitr::include_graphics("bl_convergence_acorr001.png")

```


```{r cars2, echo=FALSE,fig.cap = ". (m_BARI_POP1_3_PRIMARY_12_ACR20_independent_fixed_fixed, logit_independent_fixed_fixed) Baseline Trace plots"}
knitr::include_graphics("bl_convergence_acorr002.png")
```
````

Comment: You could assign the figure number to a variable and (echo off - R code) to increase the the figure counter.

Comment: How can I put *Figure 1*
![](bl_convergence_acorr001.png) inside the r code chunk?

Comment: have alook at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37116632/r-markdown-html-number-figures ... even better imho

Comment: I have editted my Q thanks to your comment but the issue of the dynamic numbers of iterations remains.

Comment: Where would you put the for loop? Is building an R code file where the FOR looping is then done an option? I did that on some occasions …

Comment: Normally around each one of the r code chunks cars and cars2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190044/discussion-between-wd11-and-firmo23).