# R Notebook: do not get figure captions despite having set "fig_caption: TRUE"

Tags: r, r-markdown, rnotebook

I add "fig_caption: TRUE" to the default R Notebook example:

````
---
title: "R Notebook"
output: html_notebook
fig_caption: TRUE
---
This is an [R Markdown](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com) Notebook. When you execute code within the notebook, the results appear beneath the code. 

Try executing this chunk by clicking the *Run* button within the chunk or by placing your cursor inside it and pressing *Ctrl+Shift+Enter*. 

```{r}
plot(cars)
```
````

I was expecting something like a "Figure 1" caption after the plot, but do not get any.
What should I do to get figure captions with an automatic numbering?

Comment: It's `fig.cap`, not `fig_caption`.  See [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/tufte-figures.html).  And you do actually need to provide the text of the caption.

Comment: Have you seen this link? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37116632/r-markdown-html-number-figures

Comment: You don't need to specify `fig_caption: TRUE` in the yaml. [`fig_caption: TRUE` is set by default in `html_notebook`](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/898199b9bc3df2da50edd1f7ded472e6c9e46c1b/R/html_notebook.R#L26)

Comment: `fig.cap` when running the chunk inline is not supported yet. check these two open issues on the `{rmarkdown}` and `rstudio` github repository. [#1764](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1764) and [#11113](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/11113)

Comment: @Limey fig.cap is the chunk option, fig_caption the YAML option see https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html#figure-options

Comment: @Peter Thanks, but those solutions rather look like workarounds. The only simple one is the 1st one, but requires specifying the caption for each chunk. Should I understand that something like just stating fig_caption: TRUE in the yaml is not sufficient?

Comment: @shafe, then, according to  #1764 and #11113, it looks like there is no solution at the moment. Thanks.