# rmarkdown HTML number figures not working with knitr_1.44

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, knitr, caption

Using code similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51733738/6574038). After updating `knitr_1.43` to `knitr_1.44` captions are no longer numbered and floating right. They changed something, bug or feature?

Note, there are HTML tags in captions, which worked fine in old version.

Downgrading to `knitr_1.43` does as a workaround. How to get appropriate numbering with `knitr_1.44`?

````
---
title: "My Title"
subtitle: "Subtitle"
author: "Me"
date:  "1/1/2016"
output:
   bookdown::html_document2: 
     toc: true
     toc_float: true
     toc_depth: 4
     toc_collapsed: true
     number_sections: true
     keep_md: yes
     theme: flatly
     citation_package: biblatex
header-includes: 
- \usepackage{amsmath}
- \usepackage{extarrows}
---
<style type="text/css">
  body{
    font-size: 11pt;
  }
  .tblCaptionBlue > caption{
    color: blue;
  }
  .tblCaptionRed > caption{
    color: red;
  }
</style>


```{r cars, fig.cap = "<b>An amazing plot</b>"}
plot(cars)
```
````

### knitr_1.43

[image]

### knitr_1.44

[image]

### Note

- R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16), Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit), Running under: AlmaLinux 9.2 (Turquoise Kodkod)
- RStudio 2023.06.1+524 "Mountain Hydrangea" Release (547dcf861cac0253a8abb52c135e44e02ba407a1, 2023-07-07) for RHEL 9
  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36

`sessionInfo()`

```
## R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16)
## Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
## Running under: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
## 
## Matrix products: default
## BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.10.0 
## LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.10.0
## 
## locale:
##  [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
##  [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
##  [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
##  [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
##  [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
## [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       
## 
## time zone: Europe/Zurich
## tzcode source: system (glibc)
## 
## attached base packages:
## [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
## 
## loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
##  [1] digest_0.6.33     R6_2.5.1          bookdown_0.34     fastmap_1.1.1    
##  [5] xfun_0.40         cachem_1.0.8      knitr_1.44        htmltools_0.5.6  
##  [9] rmarkdown_2.24    cli_3.6.1         sass_0.4.7        jquerylib_0.1.4  
## [13] compiler_4.3.1    rstudioapi_0.15.0 tools_4.3.1       evaluate_0.21    
## [17] bslib_0.5.1       yaml_2.3.7        jsonlite_1.8.7    rlang_1.1.1
```

Comment: Filed an issue on  their [github](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/2290).

Comment: This only happens when you have HTML tags in the `fig.cap` chunk option, which makes me think that it could be due to some changes in [this commit](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/commit/c7a423c02246ecea48a24197126d9343e126b9a6) but I'm a bit shooting in the dark here

Comment: @bretauv Confirmed, removing tags brings old behavior back, thanks. Want tags, though.

Comment: Using `fig.cap = "**An amazing plot**"` instead works fine

Comment: @bretauv Just commented I want tags. Adding `fig.alt='foo'` helps, because they really [changed something](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/2290) with generating automated alt code. But we don't want to do that with tons of scripts. Sticking with `knitr_1.43` and excluding from updating is my way to go until it's fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They were so kind and fixed the issue in dev version `knitr_1.44.1`. Install it from their `repos=`:

```
install.packages('knitr', repos='https://yihui.r-universe.dev')
```